# Appending column value till a condition is met in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I have a data frame called demo with 500 records like this

```
 ID  Age 
 1   10 
 2   15
 3   36
 4   20
 .   .
 .   .
497  40
498  5
499  12
500  20
```

in above dataframe I want to add column with values such that 25% of total records(in our case 125) them must be between 1-3 and remaining i.e 75%(from 126 onwards) must be between 4-10, such that the output looks likes this

```
ID  Age  colB
 1   10   2
 2   15   1
 3   36   1
 4   20   3
 .   .
 .   .
497  40   8
498  5    10
499  12   5
500  20   9
```

I have tried

```
    function(x) {
      a= row.names(demo)[125]
     a <- FALSE
      while (!a) {

        demo$colB <- sample(nrow(demo), c(1:3))

  }
  return(x)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `rep` and `sample`

```
demo$colB <- sample(c(rep(1:3, length.out= ceiling(nrow(demo)*.25)), 
      rep(4:10, length.out=ceiling(nrow(demo)*.75))))[seq_len(nrow(demo))]
sum(demo$colB %in% 1:3)
#[1] 125
```

Calculating the `sum` based on the other post

```
sum(demo$colB %in% 1:3)
#[1] 121
```

Both used the `set.seed(1)` for calculating the `sample` (to make it reproducible)

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
demo <- data.frame(ID = 1:500, Age = sample(10:99, 500, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: yes this worked for me Thanks for emphasizing on set.seed  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming your values in `colB` does not depend on the values of the other columns):

```
demo$colB <- sample(1:10, nrow(demo), prob = c(rep(0.25/3, 3), rep(0.75/7, 7)), replace=TRUE)
```